# Многопоточность из общего

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Вопрос о многопоточности.

Аналогия:

- дверной проём размером 2м x 3м
- человек размером 0.9м x 1.7м
- медленным шагом t = 10сек

Протоколы дверного проёма:

- Один за друим N людей. Общее время: T1 = N * t
- По 2 человека: T2 = N/2 * t  ~ в два раза быстрее
- Толпа все вместе: T3 ~ inf - дверной проход забит, хотя 1.3м сверху так и будут пытсые. Пустое пространство память пк , люди байты ... .

Или я не верно понимаю многопоточность?

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте верную пунктуацию: точки, заглавные, и т. п.  Ваш вопрос очень сложно понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо выполнить много действий то их делят на несколько параллельных потоков. Да при этом больше нагружается проц и память, но сокращается время на выполнение операции. Здесь всегда надо искать баланс между временем выполнения и загрузкой железа.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, приводят аналогию с кассами в магазине. 100 покупателей, 1 касса, "обработка" 1 покупателя - 1 минута. Пропускная способность кассы - 1 покупатель/минута, все покупатели пройдут за 100 минут.

10 касс, 10 одновременных "обработок" покупателя. Пропускная способность каждой кассы все те же 1 покупатель/минута, но все 100 покупателей пройдут за 10 минут.

Comment: но по сути есть канала еще это выходит типо человек распределитель в сбербанке, на него тоже в таком случае уходит время

Comment: Да. Поэтому в многопоточных системах, в общих узлах (которые не параллелятся) надо максимально сокращать время обработки. Либо ставить очередь.